# Como criar um sistema numerico?

Tags: conversão

#### Situação

Recentemente recebi um desafio na faculdade para fazer :

> A partir do sistema decimal `0123456789`, usando apenas os números que espelhados ainda podem ser lidos encontre o milésimo numero deste sistema.
>
> Exemplo o 8 sera o 5º numero, o 25 o 17º.

#### Desenvolvimento

Números aceitos : `0125689`

```
0   1   2   5   6   8   9
0   1   2   3   4   5   6

10  11  12  15  16  18  19
7   8   9   10  11  12  13

20  21  22  25  26  28  29
14  15  16  17  18  19  20
```

#### Minha proposta

Criar um sistema numérico de base 7, com estes "caracteres".

#### Problema

Ele não segue o mesmo padrão de [conversão de bases](http://www.matematicamuitofacil.com/naodecimais.html), estaria mais para números romanos (um tato mais complexo).
Ao somar `1+2` o resultado é `5`, `9+5 = 12`

#### Questão

Como gerenciar computacionalmente este sistema, digamos que eu queira somar 25+18. Ou qualquer outro exemplo.

#### Obs

Eu extrapolei um pouco o desafio, que seria só fazer com um *loop* removendo os números não permitidos, mas creio ser um bom estudo.

#### Pesquisas

[Sistemas de Numeração Não Decimais](http://www.matematicamuitofacil.com/naodecimais.html)
[Noções de Sistema de Numeração](http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/camyle/introducao-a-computacao-livro/livro/livro.chunked/ch03s01.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando novamente verifiquei que minha ideia se trata de fato da própria base 7, apenas com uma conversão no final.

#### Analogia

Se necessito criar uma base com `0125689` seria o mesmo que criar uma com `abcdefg`.
Com isso em mente notei que a questão, não são com caracteres envolvidos, mas sim quantos.

#### Solução

Desta forma a logica de conversão de base se mantêm.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que é feito apos isso é apenas um conversão normal de caracteres. Da mesmo forma que eu converteria :

```
a => 0, b => 1, c => 2, d => 5, e => 6, f => 8, g => 9
```

Real :

```
0 => 0, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 5, 4 => 6, 5 => 8, 6 => 9
```

#### Code

```js
var tot = 1000;
var base = 7;
var rest = [];

console.log('Numero',tot,'(10)')

while(tot>base){
 rest.push(tot%base);
 tot = Math.floor(tot/base);
}
var result = tot+rest.reverse().join('')+"";
console.log('normal', result, '(7)');

var convert = { 3 : 5, 4 : 6, 5 : 8, 6 : 9 }
for(var i in convert){
 var r = convert[i];
 result = result.replace(new RegExp(i, 'g'),r);
}
console.log('result', result, '(7) => convertido');
```

#### Leitura auxiliar

[Aritmética em Bases Não Decimais](http://www.midiacom.uff.br/~diego/disciplinas/2015_1/FAC/arquivos/aula6.pdf)